# Why DFA's configuration space is finite and PDA configuration space is infinite?

Tags: finite-automata, pushdown-automata

I read from this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144692/why-equality-is-decidable-for-regular-language-but-not-for-cfl) the term configuration space. I don't  know the meaning of *configuration space*.

What is the exactly meaning of *configuration space?*

And why DFA's configuration space is finite and PDA's configuration space is infinite? Give one example for both the cases then it could be better for me.

Comment: We call a DFA "a finite automaton" because it has finitely many configurations. We do not call a PDA "a finite automaton" because a PDA has infinitely many configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A Configuration just Means "State"

A configuration of a machine $M$ is a snapshot of the machine at a particular moment during a computational process by the machine. It includes all setting/details of the machine. It means, basically, the "state" of a machine, where "state" is in the usual sense of plain English as in "the state of a game", "the state of a kitchen" or "the state of an electrical motor". (In fact, had we not used "state" in the definition of a DFA or a PDA, we would have preferred to use "state" instead of "configuration"!)

A configuration of a machine at a particular moment determines its future behavior completely when further input are fed to that machine.

The configuration space of a machine $M$ means all possible configurations of $M$, i.e., configurations of $M$ at all possible moments.

More formally,

- given [a DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Formal_definition) $D=(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$, a configuration of $D$ is an element in $Q$, that could be associated to a particular moment of $D$. There are $|Q|$ possible configurations of $D$.
- given [a PDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#Formal_definition) $P=(Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_{0}, Z, F)$, a configuration of $P$ is an ordered pair of an element in $Q$ and its stack (with finitely many stack symbols in it), that could be associated to a particular moment of a computation by $P$. Although the content of the stack of $P$ is finite, there are infinitely many possibilities for the content, just as there are infinitely many natural numbers.  So there are $|Q|\times\infty=\infty$ possible configurations of $P$.

- given [a Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) $T=(Q,\Gamma,b,\Sigma,\delta,q_{0},F)$, a configuration of $T$ is an ordered triple of an element in $Q$ and the tape with the symbols on it and the head position, that could be a snapshot of $T$ at a particular moment while $T$ is running. There are infinitely many configurations for $T$.

Note that we could have included $\delta$, $q_0$, etc. in the definition of a configuration of a machine. However, since these elements do not change while a machine runs, there is little benefit to include them.

Also note that the (remaining) input is NOT part of a configuration of a machine, although the (remaining) input is a part of a snapshot (instantaneous description) of a computation made by the machine.

#### What is a Machine?

What does it mean by a DFA, a PDA or a Turing machine as a machine?

Take PDA as an example. The PDA machine refers to "Finite control unit" and "Stack" illustrated in the image below, excluding the "Input tape".

[image: PDA working schema, taken from https://eneskarali.github.io/automataLab/TermProject/ or https://github.com/eneskarali/automataLab/blob/master/TermProject/pda.jpg. Not licensed yet!]

A simple mental model for a PDA is a finite state automaton plus a stack with unbounded capacity. A configuration for a PDA is the current  state of its finite-state-automaton part and the current stack together with all its content. Readers are encouraged to visualize a running PDA by clicking button "Next Step" on [this page](https://eneskarali.github.io/automataLab/TermProject/), where the configuration of a PDA can be seen as the stack on the left-hand side together with the current state indicated by the red circle on the right-hand side.

Readers can also visualize a running DFA machine by various tools, such as [this page](https://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/). You can enter a regular expression such as `(a+b)*aaa(a+b)*`, which is for words with triple `a`s. Select "DFA". Click "Creat automaton". Then you can see a DFA created at its section "Transition graph". You can use section "Simulate automaton" to run that DFA. A configuration of that DFA is indicated by the state in red.

Comment: If you have a different formal definition of DFA, PDA or Turing machine, the formal definition of a configuration will, of course, change accordingly.

Comment: """For PDA ordered pair of the current state and the current stack (with all finitely many stack symbols in it). So there are $|Q|×∞=∞$ possible configurations for P.""""----- in PDA I have current state and current stack, but stack contains finite elements, so how could we say configuration space of pda is infinite? And how $|Q|×∞=∞$?

Comment: could elaborate why stack symbol you treat as $∞$? And then there are $|Q|×∞=∞$ ?

Comment: @Tigerheart, please come to [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135245/chat-with-john-l) for a chat.

Comment: Please help this question in MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451272/equivalence-between-deterministic-and-non-deterministic-counter-net